# Python reading in Data doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

So i wrote this code to combine two directories with data from this dataset :https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/cell-images-for-detecting-malaria

```
data=[]
labels=[]
for img in parasitized_data:
  try:
    img_read=plt.imread('drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Parasitized'+'/'+img)
    img_resize=cv2.resize(img_read,(50,50))
    img_array=img_to_array(img_resize)
    data.append(img_array)
    labels.append(1)
  except:
    None
for img in uninfected_data:
  try:
    img_read=plt.imread('drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Uninfected'+'/'+img)
    img_resize=cv2.resize(img_read,(50,50))
    img_array=img_to_array(img_resize)
    data.append(img_array)
    labels.append(0)
  except:
    None
```

The thing is: it works for the parasitized data, but not the uninfected data. I tried printing out the img_read and img_resize etc. which all seem to be working just fine.

Comment: Could you please give us information on what is inside the variables `parasitized_data` and `uninfected_data`?

Comment: Try using `breakpoint()` in the `except` clause and see what the issue is. The problem with bare excepts is that you might be catching errors which you should not be, it's better to catch the specific exception e g. `except ValueError`.

Comment: @AyushGarg these are just the variables for the data in the folders:     parasitized_data = os.listdir('drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Parasitized')
uninfected_data = os.listdir('drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Uninfected')

Comment: So, is it a list of all of the names (_including the extentions_) of the files? Could you show how you are getting these values?

Comment: @AyushGarg yes it is. It is all saved in my Google Drive and from there I am accessing it via the above written code

Comment: Does it give an error, or is the variable empty? Please elaborate. (Sorry I'm asking so many questions)

Comment: @Shayaan I tried it and it says: "name 'breakpoint' is not defined" for both of the functions (for the parasitized and uninfected as I run it appart from each other)

Comment: @AyushGarg I don't get an error for the function it just runs and there is no end. With the breakpoint() written in the code it says "name 'breakpoint' is not defined".

Comment: sorry what was written here was bs I get the error "cannot identify image file 'drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Parasitized/Thumbs.db' " So I am checking the files in the drive now

Comment: Can you take out the `try` and `except` clauses and then run it?

Comment: @AyushGarg same error only without the breakpoint error

Comment: You're probably on an earlier version of Python then, try using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` instead, it's Python's built in debugger.

Comment: In any case, the point is that you'll have to debug a bit more to find your error, you're getting closer with Ayush's advice - look at the error you're getting and think about why you're getting it

Comment: @Shayaan so now there is no error anymore its just running without an end

Comment: Are you sure it's running without an end? Maybe the iteration is just very long. Is it iterating at all or is it stuck at a certain line? Is it a different image each time? You'll have to answer these questions through further debugging as they come up, getting the answers through SO comments will be slow and won't build your debugging skills.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is all inside the error:

> "cannot identify image file 'drive/My Drive/Malaria detection/cell_images/Parasitized/Thumbs.db'"

As you can see, you are trying to read a `.db` file as an image. Delete this from your lists and then it should work!

Comment: sadly not I removed the files and run the code with the breakpoint() in the exception and the parasitized part works fine but the uninfected part is running endless again (I know it because I stop it after running 3 times or more the time as the parasitized part and they contain the same amount of images)

Comment: Could you please show me the full code? (Including where you define the two variable lists)

Comment: actually it like 320 characters to long for a comment

Comment: Oh ok - then please use pastebin, etc. I want to see if there is a problem with the lists itself as I suspect that is the problem here.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally found the answer: It was a Drive timeout! I uploaded the file as a Zip now, unzip it and remove the Thumbs.db and everything works fine. Thanks for your help!